# JSONB column query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

There is a `JSONB` column (`some_strings`) that has value like string array

```
---------------------
["string1","string2","string3"]
["string5"]
["string6","string7"]

-------etc-----------
```

Is there a way to make a query to get row where (some_strings) contain "string2" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return records where `string2` appears anywhere in the JSONB array:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE some_strings ?& array['string2']
```

[**Documentation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Just to note that for single keyword match just `?` is more efficient than `?&` operator with the array.